# Responsive cards with aligned footers in Bootstrap 4.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

With Bootstrap 4.4, I would like to have a deck of cards with:

- equal height (`.h-100`)
- a `.card-footer` aligned at the bottom
- responsive layout with the number of cards per row defined by the viewport width

It seems that I can't have all three of them at the same time, is that true?

To get the card footers to align at the bottom of the cards, one would place them inside a `.card-deck` div, but that does not agree at all with `<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">` for example. I have also tried to add a `.row-cols-x` class to the parent `.row`, but that does not work either.

Is it possible after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the card-deck component to archive the first both points on your list. Here is an example:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To archive the third point you can extend it in your scss files via:

```
.card-deck {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xs) {
    column-count: 1;
  } 
  @include media-breakpoint-only(sm) {
    column-count: 2;
  }  
@include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

This sets the number of columns per breakpoint. That overwrites the default behavior (having always 3 columns, but just on on xs)

Comment: Doesn't work here, I get 5 columns from `sm` to `xl` and one column with `xs`. Confirmed that the SCSS compiled all right in dev tools, the `column-count` property is there. Possibly some glitch in my setup elsewhere that interferes? I'll investigate. Thanks for your suggestion though!